# What happens if I cancel a 'pull remote changes' midway?

Tags: git, github, git-pull

I am just pulling from remote in Xcode.

It has been fetching changes for 15 minutes now ( the 'fetching changes' is still spinning)...for what it normally takes 5-30 seconds. I don't know if there is anything wrong or what. My internet speed is flawless.

Would I break anything if I cancel? ie get a messed up code. Does that ever happen? Is the process atomic?

Comment: Did my answer address your question?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, thanks. I didn't mark as the corrected answer, because I wanted to fix the issue. Yet I found out Github for us is somewhat down now. :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing a `git pull` is the same as doing as `git fetch` followed by a `git merge`.  The latter merge operations takes place completely locally between a local branch and its corresponding tracking branch, and it is not relevant to your actual question.

With regard `git fetch`, [this blog](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:cUtI9e1GBocJ:www.tothenew.com/blog/why-are-atomic-commits-a-best-practice-in-git/%20&cd=5&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=sg) appears to state that Git operations, presumably including `git fetch`, are atomic:

> Git is known to have atomic operations i.e. an environment issue will not cause git to commit half of the files into the repository and leave the rest.

Assuming this to be accurate, then either a remote tracking branch will be completely updated during a `git fetch`, or it will remain as it was.

Answer (score 0):

On the `fetch` part, you now have more assurance as to its atomicity.

With Git 2.31 (Q1 2021), "[`git fetch`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/60ecad090dab8b1c0bd436252a47c8148212bcc1/Documentation/git-fetch.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch))</sup> learns to treat ref updates atomically in all-or-none fashion, just like "[`git push`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/60ecad090dab8b1c0bd436252a47c8148212bcc1/Documentation/git-push.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push))</sup> does, with the new "`--atomic`" option.

See [commit c7b190d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c7b190dabdea16d5b1c29ae50430449a8547818f), [commit d4c8db8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d4c8db8f1b43cb26efdd53d74afce60e6d9d195a), [commit c45889f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c45889f10453864130ccbfa45815e2f4e384ab5e), [commit 929d044](https://github.com/git/git/commit/929d044575ed4f9657074f098e3a9be410d511ef), [commit 58a646a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/58a646a3688ea3c15adaf481e440e9ca2d3bce06) (12 Jan 2021) by [Patrick Steinhardt (`pks-t`)](https://github.com/pks-t).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 60ecad0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/60ecad090dab8b1c0bd436252a47c8148212bcc1), 25 Jan 2021)</sup>

> ### [`fetch`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c7b190dabdea16d5b1c29ae50430449a8547818f): implement support for atomic reference updates
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Patrick Steinhardt</sup>

> When executing a fetch, then Git will currently allocate one reference transaction per reference update and directly commit it.
> This means that fetches are non-atomic: even if some of the reference updates fail, others may still succeed and modify local references.
>
> This is fine in many scenarios, but this strategy has its downsides.
>
> - The view of remote references may be inconsistent and may show a bastardized state of the remote repository.
> - Batching together updates may improve performance in certain scenarios.
>   While the impact probably isn't as pronounced with loose references, the upcoming reftable backend may benefit as it needs to write less files in case the update is batched.
> - The reference-update hook is currently being executed twice per updated reference.
>   While this doesn't matter when there is no such hook, we have seen severe performance regressions when doing a git-fetch(1) with reference-transaction hook when the remote repository has hundreds of thousands of references.
>
> Similar to [`git push`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c7b190dabdea16d5b1c29ae50430449a8547818f/Documentation/git-push.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push))</sup> `--atomic`, this commit thus introduces atomic fetches.
>
> Instead of allocating one reference transaction per updated reference, it causes us to only allocate a single transaction and commit it as soon as all updates were received.
> If locking of any reference fails, then we abort the complete transaction and don't update any reference, which gives us an all-or-nothing fetch.
>
> Note that this may not completely fix the first of above downsides, as the consistent view also depends on the server-side.
> If the server doesn't have a consistent view of its own references during the reference negotiation phase, then the client would get the same inconsistent view the server has.
> This is a separate problem though and, if it actually exists, can be fixed at a later point.
>
> This commit also changes the way we write `FETCH_HEAD` in case `--atomic` is passed.
>
> Instead of writing changes as we go, we need to accumulate all changes first and only commit them at the end when we know that all reference updates succeeded.
> Ideally, we'd just do so via a temporary file so that we don't need to carry all updates in-memory.
> This isn't trivially doable though considering the `--append` mode, where we do not truncate the file but simply append to it.
> And given that we support concurrent processes appending to `FETCH_HEAD` at the same time without any loss of data, seeding the temporary file with current contents of `FETCH_HEAD` initially and then doing a rename wouldn't work either.
> So this commit implements the simple strategy of buffering all changes and appending them to the file on commit.

`fetch-options` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c7b190dabdea16d5b1c29ae50430449a8547818f/Documentation/fetch-options.txt#L10-L13):

> ### `--atomic`
>
> Use an atomic transaction to update local refs. Either all refs are
> updated, or on error, no refs are updated.